# ssl not displaying in first visit in codeigniter website

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, ssl, config

i have ssl installed in my codeigniter website which is live and also I have enabled forced https option, my host is hostinger, SSL issuer: Let's Encrypt Authority X3.

the problem here is when the user first visit the website its showing without SSL "not secure", then if u go to another page its showing SSL and then if u go to homepage again the SSL is present, the problem is in the first visit using the searchbar of the browser, everytime when u use the searchbar of the browser this happens, any device and browser its like this.

The live URL is below is my config.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

this is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: _"I have enabled forced https option"_ - Where and how?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, in hostinger there is an option for forced https

Comment: Then it seems to be an issue on your hosting companies side. Your site allow both http and https for all pages. The only reason it seems to work when you click go to other page by clicking on the site is because you have https in the links. You can change https to http on any page and it will show it without https.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is there anyway in htaccess, that I can force it to https

Comment: Did you try the below answer from @ŁukaszGaryga?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes its seem to work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set redirection in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat - Please edit your question and include the htaccess as well since it's highly relevant information for your question.

Comment: Don't add code that aren't JS and can't be run on it's own as a snippet.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is this the right way to force https?

Comment: Why not test it and see?